# Split HTML into virtual pages

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have long content (multiple content with imgaes, lists, divs, text, etc...). I want to show this content to user as virtual PDF pages. I dont want to generate PDF, just show this HTML content as pages (defined by width/height) with same header/footer. It should look like in image bellow, as you can see on first page, I want to split that text and show in next page:

[image: This is how it should looks like]

I´m working this app on React. I dont know what will be in this content, every render will be different (with different content based on user activity).

Do you have any suggestions how to do this? (CSS solutions, or JS, or I dont know maybe some React lib ...)

Comment: What is the nature of the content? Is it plain html or an array of React elements or something else?

Comment: It is HTML generated by React component

Comment: I'm saying that because I don't know of any css able to do layout discontinuously and therefore the content will have to be parsed. It would be simpler to act before html generation.

Comment: Yes the only way I can think of is to look at the HTML content and figure out some way to split it into chunks that would fit in each page logically and then pass each of those to a page component.

Comment: @KristiánStroka the solution didn't work for you?

Comment: Yes perfect solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a naive but working implementation.

The idea is to mount the html into an offscreen div which has the same dimensions as the pages we're trying to render.

Then iterate over the elements (ie [children](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) from parsed html) of this offscreen div and query the dom using [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to find the first overflowing element.

We then remove all elements before the overflowing one from the offscreen div and cache them in an array.

Start over for a new chunk until there is no more elements in the offscreen div.

Adapting this to React is just a matter of using [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) with the html content of each page.

(the display flex is just there to force flowing of elements, but any layout would do provided it's the same in offscreenDiv and in page)

```js
function generateRandomContent() {
  var alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var content = "";
  // we will generate 100 random elements displaying their index to keep track of what's happening
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var type = parseInt(Math.random() * 2, 10);
    switch (type) {
      case 0: // text, generates and random p block
        content = content + "<p>" + i + " ";
        var numWords = 10 + parseInt(Math.random() * 50, 10);
        for (var j = 0; j < numWords; j++) {
          var numLetters = 2 + parseInt(Math.random() * 15, 10);
          if (j > 0) {
            content = content + " ";
          }
          for (var k = 0; k < numLetters; k++) {
            content = content + alph[parseInt(Math.random() * 26, 10)];
          }
          
        }
        content = content + "</p>";
        break;
      case 1: // colored div, generates a div of random size and color
        var width = 30 + parseInt(Math.random() * 20, 10) * 10;
        var height = 30 + parseInt(Math.random() * 20, 10) * 10;
        var color = "rgb(" + parseInt(Math.random() * 255, 10) + ", " + parseInt(Math.random() * 255, 10) + ", " + parseInt(Math.random() * 255, 10) + ")";
        content = content + '<div style="width: ' + width + 'px; height: ' + height + 'px; background-color: ' + color + '">' + i + '</div>';
        break;
       
    }
  }
  return content;
}

function getNodeChunks(htmlDocument) {
  var offscreenDiv = document.createElement('div');
  offscreenDiv.className = 'page';
  offscreenDiv.style.position = 'absolute';
  offscreenDiv.style.top = '-3000px';
  offscreenDiv.innerHTML = htmlDocument;
  offscreenDiv.display = 'flex';
  offscreenDiv.flexWrap = 'wrap';
  document.body.appendChild(offscreenDiv);
  offscreenRect = offscreenDiv.getBoundingClientRect();
  // console.log('offscreenRect:', offscreenRect);
  var chunks = [];
  var currentChunk = []
  for (var i = 0; i < offscreenDiv.children.length; i++) {
    var current = offscreenDiv.children[i];
    var currentRect = current.getBoundingClientRect();
    currentChunk.push(current);
    if (currentRect.bottom > (offscreenRect.bottom)) {
      // current element is overflowing offscreenDiv, remove it from current chunk
      currentChunk.pop();
      // remove all elements in currentChunk from offscreenDiv
      currentChunk.forEach(elem => elem.remove());
      // since children were removed from offscreenDiv, adjust i to start back at current eleme on next iteration
      i -= currentChunk.length;
      // push current completed chunk to the resulting chunklist
      chunks.push(currentChunk);
      // initialise new current chunk
      currentChunk = [current];
      offscreenRect = offscreenDiv.getBoundingClientRect();
    }
  }
  // currentChunk may not be empty but we need the last elements
  if (currentChunk.length > 0) {
    currentChunk.forEach(elem => elem.remove());
    chunks.push(currentChunk);
  }
  // offscreenDiv is not needed anymore
  offscreenDiv.remove();
  return chunks;
}

function appendChunksToPages(chunks) {
    var container = document.getElementsByClassName('root_container')[0];
    chunks.forEach((chunk, index) => {
      // ex of a page header
      var header = document.createElement('div');
      header.innerHTML = '<h4 style="margin: 5px">Page ' + (index + 1) + '</h4>';
      container.appendChild(header);
      var page = document.createElement('div');
      page.className = 'page';
      chunk.forEach(elem => page.appendChild(elem));
      container.appendChild(page);
    });
}

// generateRandom content outputs raw html, getNodeChunks returns
// an array of array of elements, the first dimension is the set of
// pages, the second dimension is the set of elements in each page
// finally appendChunks to pages generates a page for each chunk 
// and adds this page to the root container
appendChunksToPages(getNodeChunks(generateRandomContent()));
```

```css
 
 .page {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 700px;
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="root_container"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, The code works great, but do you have any suggestions on handling tables? since the whole table is read as one chunk it will not split it up. So if the table is longer than one page it will overflow without creating new pages.

Comment: Do you have solution for deeply nested structure, when several levels of that structure acts like a virtual wrappers for other purposes and do not mind to be split in half between pages?

Comment: This solution is not robust enough to handle deeply nested html because it pocesses only one level of children. To deal with deeply nested html to process nodes recursively with trial and error: start writing the node in the offscreen div, if it has subnodes, recusively decide if it fits on the page, if it fits so be it, otherwise duplicate it, split where it overflowed and distribute the remaining children on a new page. I may have a try at it in another answer if more people are interested.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the other answer by remix23, I was trying to do something along the same lines by formatting an html document before turning into pdf to print out on paper. I found CSS formatting to be my answer https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/designing-for-print-with-css/

I am not sure if this is the solution you are looking for but using

```
<style>
    @media print {
        div { break-inside: avoid; }
    }
</style>
```

was all I needed before I could open the html document in my browser and use its inbuilt ctrl-P to see a "virtual PDF". This method also let me modify margins and specify width/height of the paper.