# How to do MS Word document-like pagination in a React app?

Tags: reactjs

I've been working on a React app that allows me to create exams for printing. Because the exams are intended to be printed, in the app there are visual page breaks so a teacher can see the layout of the exam before printing it.

Right now I have a Page component that contains a Question component as a child. Something like:

```
<Page size='A4' layout='portrait'>
    <Question question={data} />
</Page>
```

As long as a question can fit on one page, there is no problem. But some questions are too long for a single page and therefore need to be broken up over multiple pages.

Can anyone provide advice on how to accomplish this? I know how to measure child components, but I'm not sure how to tell react 'when this height is reached, close the page tag and open a new one'. When a question straddles multiple pages, I will also need to conditionally add content to each page like 'This question continues on the next page' on the previous page, and 'Question X continued' on the new page.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. You'd be a saint if you'd tell me how you did once you find an answer.

Similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54980382/split-html-into-virtual-pages | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202324/split-text-into-pages-and-present-separately-html5

None of these worked for me, because I wanted to keep children as React components.

Comment: Following up since in reactjs how to achive this.

Comment: i have written an javacript funtion which runs externally by accessing dom directly and change the redux state, but the problem is this method is not consistent expecting some solution from community